# I'm feeling lucky

Tags: code-golf

Write the shortest function that returns the content of the first result of a Google search ("I'm feeling lucky").

Example:

```
lucky('cat');
```

Might return something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cats are cool</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>CAAAAAAAAAAATSSSSSSSSSS!!!!!!!!</h1>
    <p>
      Cats are so cool!
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Bash, 46 bytes

```
l()(wget -UM -qO- "gogle.de/search?btnI&q=$1")
```

Uses the actual *I'm feeling lucky* feature, just like the other answers.

Gogle blacklists some user agents (including WGet's, cURL's and Java's), but **M** seems to work just fine.

Comment: Why does `gogle.de` even exist?

Comment: To catch typos. `googl.de` would work as well.

Comment: @professorfish `gogle.com` exists too. Unfortunatly `googl.co.uk` redirects to a dodgy ad site.

Comment: @BetaDecay Curiously, it redirects me to a different page every time.

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, 79 / 145

I borrowed the `btnI` trick from @rink.attendant.6 for this solution. Thanks Beta Decay for shortening it by 2 characters.

```ruby
require'open-uri'
f=->q{URI(URI.escape"http://gogle.de/search?btnI&q="+q).read}
```

I also have a solution which actually gets the first result from the results page, which is 145 bytes.

```ruby
require'open-uri'
f=->q{open(URI.extract(URI(URI.escape"http://google.com/search?q=#{q}").read.split('class="r"')[1])[0].split("&amp;")[0]).read}
```

Answer (score 5):

### PHP, <s>157</s> <s>105/87</s> <s>102/87</s> 100/85

#### Using [`file_get_contents`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```php
<?php function l($q){return file_get_contents("https://google.ca/search?btnI&q=".rawurlencode($q));}
```

Without allowing for spaces in the search term it's only 87 characters:

```php
<?php function l($q){return file_get_contents("https://google.ca/search?q=$q&btnI");}
```

#### Original versions using [cURL](https://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

I suppose that short array syntax can be used on PHP 5.4+:

```php
<?php function l($q){$ch=curl_init("https://google.ca/search?btnI=1&q=".rawurlencode($q));curl_setopt_array($ch,[19913=>1,52=>1]);return curl_exec($ch);}
```

Otherwise it's five more characters with the normal array initializer, 162:

```php
<?php function l($q){$ch=curl_init("https://google.ca/search?btnI=1&q=".rawurlencode($q));curl_setopt_array($ch,[19913=>1,52=>1]);return curl_exec($ch);}
```

Version that **does not allow spaces in the search term**: No need for URL encoding (138):

```php
<?php function l($q){$ch=curl_init("https://google.ca/search?q=$q&btnI=1");curl_setopt_array($ch,[19913=>1,52=>1]);return curl_exec($ch);}
```

Ungolfed using constants

```php
<?php
function l($q){
$ch = curl_init("https://google.ca/search?btnI=1&q=" . rawurlencode($q));
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1
  ));
return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Comment: You should be able to replace `"https://google.ca/search?q=".rawurlencode($q)."&btnI=1"` with `"http://google.ca/search?btnI=1&q=".rawurlencode($q)`

Comment: Just realized that, changing it for both my answers

Comment: Are you using SSL for any particular reason?

Comment: You can replace `btnI=1` with `btnI`.

Answer (score 4):

### C#, <s>183</s> <s>180</s> 178

This is my first time ever writing code in C# so it could probably use improvement. Feedback is welcome!

```csharp
string l(string q){return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString((new System.Net.WebClient()).DownloadData("https://google.ca/search?btnI&q="+System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(q)));}
```

#### Unminified

```csharp
string l(string q) {
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
        (new System.Net.WebClient()).DownloadData(
            "https://google.ca/search?btnI&q=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(q)
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: You can just use 'DownloadString' and avoid the Encoding bit.

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 40 bytes

Thought, I'll finally give the `g` method a try

```
{"gogle.de/search?btnI&q="\S/"%20"*+g}:F
```

This creates a method/block `F` which can be used like

```
{"gogle.de/search?btnI&q="\S/"%20"*+g}:F; "cats and dogs"F
```

This is how functions work in CJam ..

Doesn't work in online interpreter, so you will have to [download and use](http://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/) the Java one.

Note that Google denies all requests with Java user agent, so you will have to start CJam with an additional flag `-Dhttp.agent=M`

Comment: +1 for CJam and you, -1 for Google. They return 403 if the User-Agent is Java. I hope @aditsu will solve this.

Comment: @aditsu - Any plans for that ?

Comment: This will only work if you spoof the user agent by passing, e.g., `-Dhttp.agent=M` to the Java interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 - 78

Uses `gogle.de` for brevity. Run as `f(query)`.

```
f=lambda x:__import__("requests").get("http://gogle.de/search?btnI&q="+x).text
```

If you want to have spaces in your query it's 98 characters.

```
f=lambda x:__import__("requests").get("http://gogle.de/search?btnI&q="+x.replace(" "," %20")).text
```