# Code Golf : Parsing google results

Tags: code-golf, parsing, internet

When you search something on google, within the results page, the user can see green links, for the first page of results.

In the shortest form possible, in bytes, using any language, display those links to stdout in the form of a list. Here is an example, for the first results of the stack exchange query :

[image: A screen capture]

#### Input :

you choose : the URL (`www.google.com/search?q=stackexchange&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8`) or just `stackexchange`

#### Output :

```
french.stackexchange.com/, stackoverflow.com/, fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange_Network, en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange,...
```

#### Rules :

- You may use URL shorteners or other search tools/APIs as long as the results would be the same as searching https://www.google.com.
- It's ok if your program has side effects like opening a web browser so the cryptic Google html/js pages can be read as they are rendered.
- You may use browser plugins, userscripts...
- If you can't use stdout, print it to the screen with, eg. a popup or javascript alert !
- You don't need the ending / or the starting http(s)://
- You should not show any other link
- Shortest code wins !
- Good luck !

EDIT :
This golf ends the 07/08/15.

Comment: Since you are using `google.fr`, do we have to use that as well?

Comment: You can use any google you want. I'm french, so I used .fr, but you could use .com or .anything :) Dosn't matter

Comment: And shortened URLs such as [`gogle.de`](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39786/im-feeling-lucky#comment91440_39817) are fine as well?

Comment: You may use URL shorteners or other search tools/APIs as long as the results would be the same as searching https://www.google.com, so yes

Comment: I've made some minor formatting changes - feel free to reverse any that are not how you want.

Comment: In case you're tempted: remember [you can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I can't find an online Python interpreter that will let me use `urllib` or anything web related.

Comment: @mbomb007 I'm pretty sure IdeOne supports urllib

Comment: The method I found for using `urllib` required `import json` as well. You seem to have done it without that.

Comment: can we use google.search API libraries?

Comment: Yup :) (But, by the way, did you see the date of the challenge ? It's cool, but, a few months old :p)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Bash + grep + lynx, 38

Since we can open a web browser, then I will use `lynx`:

```
lynx -dump $1|grep -Po '(?<=d:)[^&]+'
```

(Thanks to @manatwork for `grep` usage instead of `sed`)

We pass in the whole URL in as a parameter:

```
$ ./gr.sh "www.google.com/search?q=stackexchange&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8"
http://stackexchange.com/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange
https://twitter.com/stackexchange
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin
https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis
https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Basics.md
https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/stack-exchange
$
```

Which gives the same list as:

[image]

Comment: Well that's handy :D

Comment: `sed` good. `sed` long. Try GNU `grep`: `grep -Po '(?<=d:)[^&]+'`

Comment: @manatwork Yes, of course - thanks!

Comment: Was the answer title copypasted? ;) None of `bash`, `lynx` or `sed` (and now `grep`) is part of coreutils.

Comment: @manatwork I was not implying that `bash` or `lynx` were part of coreutils - thats why they are listed separately.  For some reason I had the mistaken belief that `grep` and `sed` were coreutils - I've fixed that.

Comment: I believe you can also do: `lynx -dump $1|grep -Po 'd:\K[^&]+'` (untested)

Comment: Best answer to date !

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>91</s> 77 bytes

```
require'open-uri';open(gets).read.scan(/ed:(.*?)\+/){|x|puts URI.decode x[0]}
```

<s>Would've been shorter without all the `require`s. ARGH!!!</s> **EDIT**: So, turns out, I *don't* need the second require! Thanks to @manatwork for pointing that out.

Older version (with the useless `require`):

```
require'open-uri';require 'uri';open(gets).read.scan(/ed:(.*?)\+/){|x|puts URI.decode x[0]}
```

Comment: Rules allow the use of command line options as long as you count them too: http://pastebin.com/PnpjnXji (If you feel this is unfair style, feel free to use only the change in the code block.)

Comment: Are you sure you need to explicitly `require'uri'`? In 2.1.2 I use the `URI` module becomes available after requiring open-uri.

Comment: @manatwork Thank you! Updated.

Comment: Just for my curiosity: any reason to not change the code block as in my pastebin alternative? (Of course, I'm curious about technical reasons, not personal reasons, if that hold you back.)

Comment: @manatwork I need to, but I was too lazy to figure out the byte count at the moment. :)

Answer (score 4):

**Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 135**

```
StringJoin/@(Cases[URLExecute["www.google.com/search",{"q"->#},"XMLObject"],XMLElement["cite",_,l_]:>l,-1]/.XMLElement["b",_,{s_}]:>s)&
```

more readable:

```
StringJoin/@(Cases[
    URLExecute["www.google.com/search",{"q"->#},"XMLObject"], 
    XMLElement["cite",_,l_]:>l,-1] /. 
    XMLElement["b",_,{s_}]:>s)
```

Comment: Are the spaces really necessary? Without them, I get [136 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#StringJoin%2F%40%28Cases%5BURLExecute%5B%22www.google.com%2Fsearch%22%2C%7B%22q%22-%3E%23%7D%2C%20%22XMLObject%22%5D%2CXMLElement%5B%22cite%22%2C%5f%2Cl%5f%5D%3A%3El%2C-1%5D%2F.XMLElement%5B%22b%22%2C%5f%2C%7Bs%5f%7D%5D%3A%3Es%29%26).

Comment: not necessary at all...I really should tighten this up..

Comment: Can you do something like [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44316/11259) to shorten this?

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 141 bytes

Nowhere near Digital Trauma's answer, but it was fun to work out the regex :D

```python
import re
print('\n'.join(map(lambda x:x[3:],re.findall('te>http[s]?://\w+\.[a-z]+[](/a-z\.)?]+',__import__("requests").get(input()).text))))
```

For input `http://www.google.com/search?q=stackexchange&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8` the program outputs:

```python
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/
https://twitter.com/
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id...
https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/
https://www.facebook.com/
https://github.com/
```

[Implements grc's tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54369/30525)

Comment: Do you really need to use `__import__`?

Comment: Also, use an `[x for x in spam]` construct instead of `map`. That will save you a good number of bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Factor, 31 bytes

There happens to be a library for this.

```
[ google-search [ url>> ] map ]
```