# Golfing with User Agents

Tags: code-golf, tips, internet

Usually when performing an internet challenge, there's no problem with having to specify a user agent, but when it comes to dealing with Google, it changes.

Google blacklists the Urllib user agent, presumably to stop spambots, so you have to specify a user agent. This takes up many bytes, and is frankly rather annoying.

[Example 1.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54134/30525) [Example 2.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40019/30525) [Example 3.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40027)

***Note:*** I have updated my Python answers to use the tip suggested below

So how do you get around this problem using the shortest number of bytes?

Comment: Are you sure this question isn't missing a language tag?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Well although the question is oriented towards Python, I was hoping that the solution could be used to help with other languages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [requests module](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/), if allowed, is much shorter and easier than urllib in Python (2 and 3):

```py
__import__('requests').get('url').text
```

On my computer, the user agent defaults to:

```
python-requests/2.3.0 CPython/3.4.3 Darwin/14.3.0
```