# What's on the TV?

Tags: code-golf, parsing, internet

### Challenge

Write a program which, using the XML data from the site [here](http://www.bleb.org/tv/data/listings/0/bbc1.xml), display the name of the programme which is currently showing on BBC 1.

### Information

All times are given at London time (GMT+1 at the time of posting and GMT+0 after the 30th October). Therefore, you should convert your local time to London time.

Each programme is given a start and end time. If the current time is after the start time and before the end time of a programme, that programme is currently showing. Your programme may handle overlaps in anyway you wish.

Your output must be the programme title, like so:

```
BBC News
```

However, if the programme has a subtitle (shown by the presence of the subtitle tag), the output should be like so:

```
Steptoe and Son: The Piano
```

Where *Steptoe and Son* is the title and *The Piano* is the subtitle. An example programme with a subtitle is as follows:

```
<programme>
    <subtitle>Newcastle</subtitle>
    <title>Flog It!</title>
    <end>1710</end>
    <start>1610</start>
    <desc>
      Antiques series. Paul Martin presents from the Discovery Museum in Newcastle. The items uncovered include a book of autographs with a local connection. Also in HD. [S]
    </desc>
</programme>
```

URL shorteners are disallowed but XML parsing libraries are allowed.

### Winning

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Can you give a test case with a subtitle tag, because there (currently) is none in the linked xml file.

Comment: @KarlKastor There you go

Comment: Do we have to convert the local time to London time?

Comment: @KarlKastor Yes, you do

Comment: Must the code always grab the latest TV show, or can we grab the latest TV show *as of now* and use it?

Comment: @ColdGolf What? No, it has to be the latest

Comment: The link in your post has multiple show names. Which one do we use?

Comment: @ColdGolf The question describes how you use the start and end times to find the latest show...

Comment: I presume dates after midnight reflect programs that are on the day _after_ the date specified by the date attribute in the root channel element?

Comment: Wait, what if there is no program currently showing? That seems to be the case as of `0423 UTC+1` according to the link provided, as the very first item shown is a program that starts at `0600 UTC+1`.

Comment: @R.Kap "Your programme may handle overlaps in anyway you wish." I imagine this includes dead air (so I would think any of: "None"; <previous program>; <next program>; something completely different -  would be fine). EDIT: Nope - currently showing is "BBC News" - note the date says 20th but it's the 21st - look near the end of the file :)

Comment: @HWalters Yes, they do

Comment: What exactly makes this "quick golf"?

Comment: @MartinEnder I suppose because I wrote it quickly :D

Comment: IMO this would be better if xml libraries were not allowed.

Comment: @SeanBean That'd change the focus of the question though, and probably make it a dupe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Bash + curl + XMLStarlet, 166 characters

```bash
d=`TZ=Europe/London date +%H%M`
curl -s bleb.org/tv/data/listings/0/bbc1.xml|xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//programme[start<=$d and end>$d]" -v title -m subtitle -o :\  -v .
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ date 
Mon Aug 22 14:17:07 EEST 2016

bash-4.3$ bash bbc.sh 
Bargain Hunt: Carmarthen
```

Comment: I'm not good at bash scripting , but is it possible to produce the website address via decompressing compressed version of address or something similar ?

Comment: Not really. Is too short for compression. Uncompressed has 36 bytes, compressed with gzip has 56 bytes. Other tools I tried produce even bigger result.

Answer (score 5):

## Python, <s>440</s> <s>428</s> <s>426</s> <s>398</s> 395 Bytes

*-31 Bytes thanks to @Loovjo*

Throws an error when it found the date.

```
import re,pytz,urllib
from datetime import*
x=urllib.urlopen("http://www.bleb.org/tv/data/listings/0/bbc1.xml").read().split("</p")[:-1]
for m,n in enumerate(re.search("\d*</s",i).group()for i in x):
 if n>datetime.strftime(datetime.now(pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/London')),"%H%M"):print re.search(">.*?</t",x[m-1]).group()[1:-3],": "+re.search("e>.*?</s",x[m-1]).group()[2:-3],_
```

*Please don't hurt me for parsing xml with regex.*

#### version using a xml parser, 398 Bytes

```
import re,pytz,urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from datetime import*
x=list(ET.parse(urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.bleb.org/tv/data/listings/0/bbc1.xml")[0]).getroot())
for m,n in enumerate(i.find("start").text for i in x):
 if n>datetime.strftime(datetime.now(pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/London')),"%H%M"):print x[m-1].find("title").text,": "+x[0].find("subtitle").text,_
```

Comment: It's okay, we've only got problems with the parsing of HTML with regex ;)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think you can replace the `break` with something that causes an error (such as `1/0` (or maybe even `_`)). I'm pretty sure your submissions can exit with an error.

Comment: Are third party libs allowed? If yes, then you change `urllib` to use `requests` in your first example: `x=requests.get(link).text.split("</p")[:-1]`. That will save you 2 bytes.

Comment: @Zizouz212 [Yes, requests is allowed](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54369/30525)