# Download a file from the Internet

Tags: code-golf, internet

## Introduction

Yes, it's as simple as that. Download any file from the internet!

## Rules

You must use your language's API.

You must output the file you downloaded to STDOUT, the console, a file, etc.

Input should be empty, or the URL you wish to download, but the url must count to byte count..

Good luck!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Bash, <s>21</s> <s>17</s> <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```sh
curl ai
```

Comment: `curl` is not a tool that already exists? :)

Comment: @AbelTom this is "your language's API"

Comment: `curl ai` no need for http://

Comment: could you please explain what `curl 3.ly` does?

Comment: @bolov this uses the command line program `curl` to download the page at `http://3.ly`

Comment: Why not `wget ai`?

Comment: @SIGSEGV: Because that does not output to _stdout_.

Comment: This doesn't work for me?  What's `ai` supposed to be? Gives `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ai` here.

Comment: @Riker It's the [ccTLD for Anguilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ai). `curl ai` gave me http://209.59.119.34

Comment: @martin yea, it only works on some machines.  It's confirmed to work on some linux distros, but not mac and not all windows machines.

Answer (score 13):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 29 bytes

```
{saveResource"http://ai","a"}
```

This is an anonymous function that creates a file `a` containing the HTML code of `http://ai`.

Comment: Now to convince them to run an FTP server...

Comment: How is that url valid?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Why wouldn't it be valid? It has a protocol, a hostname, and no port, path or query string but those are all optional. Are you asking why ai is a valid hostname?

Comment: @immibis Isn't the TLD required?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei `ai` ***is*** a TLD. Usually TLDs don't resolve to addresses that host websites, but this one apparently does.

Comment: @immibis, So `ai` is the hostname and the TLD at the same time? What do you mean by "this one apparently does"? Do you mean that you can access it in a browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58570/discussion-between-immibis-and-iulian-onofrei).

Comment: For those who - like me - the URL does not resolve, you can probably view it by using the IP address directly: [209.59.119.34](http://209.59.119.34/)

Comment: Apparently this URL requires a specific DNS server. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 6):

## MATL, 8 bytes

```
'v.ht'Xi
```

The URL provided to `Xi` (`urlread`) is prepended with `http://` if it isn't already. Additionally the output of `urlread` contains the contents of the response and this is implicitly printed when the program exits.

Unfortunately this does not work for the online compilers since loading data from an arbitrary URL is disallowed in online-mode, so here's a GIF.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

## Bash, <del>45</del> 43 bytes

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/ai/80;echo GET />&3;cat<&3
```

opens a tcp socket with ai site on file descriptor 3, issues a get, and cats the result.
perhaps can be golfed further.

Comment: You can remove the double quotes `"` around `GET /`.

Comment: Amazing! This is very good, even if it is not the shortest.

Answer (score 5):

## PowerShell, 7 Bytes

Since we're all using `www.ai`...

```
irm ai.
```

uses `Invoke-RestMethod` - prints the result to StdOut

alternate answer, saves to file named 'a' in run directory, using `Invoke-WebRequest` and `-OutFile` param.

```
iwr ai. -OutF a
```

Comment: I'm going to nitpick that `irm` won't download `any file`, as requested in the question, because if the server returns json or xml, it will be turned into a PSObject instead. And `irm ai.` doesn't work for me - it says name cannot be resolved... I get `"$(irm g.cn)"` as a suggestion.

Comment: good point regarding `irm` - @John Hathwood - does this still fit the challenge or need to be changed? i'm a little unclear on 'any file' - it outputs a 'parsed' copy of any json or xml, all other files are returned raw.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler what version of PS are you using? do you get anything running `nslookup ai.` or `nslookup www.ai 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Aye, it works querying against Google DNS, it's a local Windows DNS server that can't resolve it. OK.  PSv4 as well, but that's not involved, same at a cmd prompt.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler always something simple aha, i'll wait for the challenge author to confirm if the above is ok, but most likely the 15-byte `iwr` answer will be the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica 18 Bytes

```
URLDownload@"v.ht"
```

Comment: I think `FetchURL` works

Comment: Think you mean `URLFetch` which requires a Mathematica version before 11.

Comment: URLFetch still works in the current version but at some point will probably be fully deprecated, and there did use to be a FetchURL in Utilities`URLTools` 
 https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLFetch.html

Answer (score 4):

### C#, <strike>96</strike> 93 bytes

```
async()=>Console.Write(await new System.Net.Http.HttpClient().GetStringAsync("http://3.ly"));
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Thanks! I lurk occasionally but I needed some fun today c:

Answer (score 3):

## JS (ES6), <s>38</s> <s>36</s> <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
fetch`//ai`.then(x=>x.text())
```

Depending on the promise consensus, (41 bytes)

```
fetch`//ai`.then(x=>x.text()).then(alert)
```

Comment: Until we reach a consensus on Promises, I'd say you'll need to `alert` this.

Comment: Do 10 votes a consensus make? (Genuine question that; how many votes do we need for it to considered accaptable?)

Comment: Does `text` return a promise or does `...then(x=>alert(x.text()))` work?

Comment: @immibis, It returns a `Promise`, unfortunately.

Comment: @programmer5000, shouldn't the first version be a function (+3 bytes) in order to return the promise?

Comment: @Shaggy it's acceptable now. The consensus is +5 and 2:1 ratio of up to downvotes.

Comment: Do you have a source for that, @Riker?

Comment: @Shaggy it used to be in the meta itself, it was accidentally edited out. Martin has confirmed in chat a couple times that's what it is. (iirc the loopholes post is the same)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the info, @Riker.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 22 bytes

If `allow_url_include=1` is in your ini file:

```
<?=include"http://ai";
```

Answer (score 3):

## C (Clang, ARMv7-a Linux/Android, AT&T Wireless), 162 bytes

Since we're hardcoding URLs, why not hardcode ISPs?

```c
main(s){int b[500]={5<<28|2,**((int***)gethostbyname("ai"))[4]};connect(s=socket(2,1,0),b,16);write(s,"GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n",16);read(s,b,-1);read(s,b,-1);puts(b);}
```

I can't show a demo because none of the demos have online enabled :(

This abuses two things. One is that I assume `http://ai` is smaller than 2000 bytes and just casually read a max of 4GB onto the stack (what could possibly go wrong), and two is that I take advantage of how I discovered that AT&T Wireless converts `\n` to `\r\n` in HTTP requests for some reason (new data saving hack?).

Termux screenshot, showing how it works on data (AT&T via Cricket) but *not* on my Wi-Fi (Xfinity).

[image: The only thing AT&T is good for?]

Ungolfed and commented:

**note**: I have removed the punning and buffer reusing for this.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Look up the IP address of http://ai
    // Note that I mess around with type punning and the documented
    // layout of the structure in the golfed version.
    struct hostent *ent = gethostbyname("ai");
    // Extract the first IP address (already in network order)
    uint32_t ip;
    memcpy(&ip, ent->h_addr_list[0], sizeof(uint32_t));
    // Create the sockaddr struct
    struct sockaddr_in header = (struct sockaddr_in) {
        .sin_family = AF_INET,
        .sin_port = htons(80),
        .sin_addr = { ip }
    };
    // Copy over to the pun
    struct sockaddr_storage header_raw;
    memcpy(&header_raw, &header, sizeof(header));

    // Create an IPv4 socket
    int soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    // Connect the socket to the interwebs
    connect(soc, (const struct sockaddr *)&header_raw, sizeof(header_raw));

    // Send an HTTP GET request
    // Note that because It Works™ on AT&T, I use \n instead of the proper \r\n. Two newlines are still required though.
#ifdef ATT
    const char get_request[] = "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n";
#else
    const char get_request[] = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
#endif
    write(soc, get_request, strlen(get_request));

    char buf[2000] = {0};
    // Note: I use -1 to just read the entire thing. Hopefully it is all shorter than
    // 1999 chars :P
#ifdef BUF_HACK
    size_t len = -1;
#else
    size_t len = sizeof(buf) - 1;
#endif
    // Receive the HTTP response header
    read(soc, buf, len);
    // But ignore it because I don't care about parsing HTTP stuff
    // Just read again for the real data
    read(soc, buf, len);
    // Print to stdout (assuming the HTTP header was shorter)
    puts(buf);
    // I don't actually bother closing the socket in the golfed code, sue me.
#ifndef RESOURCE_HOG
    close(soc);
#endif
}
```

I just decided to see how painful this was, I knew before I started that it didn't have a chance.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>55</s> <s>49</s> 47 bytes

<s>Not shorter but</s> I really thought I could go further.

```python
from urllib import*
urlopen('http://ai').read
```

Comment: I think `from urllib import*\nurlopen('http://g.co').read` is a valid submission as the second line is an unnamed function (just like an unnamed lambda function)

Comment: You need to remove the trailing brackets. It would be a snippet instead oft an function otherwise

Comment: `IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Are you using TIO? Code run in TIO doesn't have access to the internet.

Comment: I don't know what TIO is.

Comment: Can you access http://ai in a regular browser?

Comment: @totallyhuman What is `http://ai` ? Is this a valid address? I cannot open it in the browser.

Comment: It works for me. Might be restricted..?

Comment: @totallyhuman nvm. Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152106/why-do-these-urls-without-a-tld-resolve-to-a-webpage and I could access it from the phone.

Comment: May be helpful: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54356/golfing-with-user-agents

Answer (score 2):

## R, 24 bytes

```
readLines('http://g.co')
```

prints the output to console in the usual R format -- vector of strings, one element per line of the site.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 13 bytes

```
URLFetch@"ai"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Vim Ex command, 14 bytes

```
e http://3.ly/
```

Opens the URL as a new buffer. Netrw seriously suffers from a restrictive URL format.

Answer (score 1):

### nc -v v.ht 80 < file - 31 bytes

Where file contains:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: v.ht\r\n
\r\n
```

I profess ignorance about how I should score this. The file is 31 bytes and contains the URL I want, the `-v` flag value decides if I get the file I want or an error response.

Comment: `nc ai 80<<<GET\ /` works for me for 18B

Comment: I saw other people using that but it doesn't resolve on my machine. I might be able to find a more permissive server but this one needs the `Host` value. I can maybe remove the last two `\r\n` couplets

Comment: Odd, my machine wouldn't resolve `ai` for `curl` or `wget` but does for `nc`. try `ai.` (trailing dot), or `3.ly`. It's an error page, but that's still within the bounds of the challenge.

Comment: Hmm, if the error page is acceptable then I could send a body of just `\n`. I'll try some more stuff when I get home

Answer (score 1):

## Kdb+, <s>34</s> 15 bytes

**KDB+ >= 3.4**

```
 q).Q.hg`http://ai
```

from [here](http://code.kx.com/wiki/DotQ/DotQDothg).

**KDB+ < 3.4**

```
q)`:http://ai"GET / HTTP/1.0",4#"\n"
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Thu, 11 May 2017 21:45:01 GMT\r\nServer: Apache/1.3..
```

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 71 bytes

```rkt
(require net/url)(port->string(get-pure-port(string->url"http://ai")))
```

Comment: Don't see too many Racket answers around here.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 33 bytes

Sadly, this only works on the J shell.

[image: J HTTP demo]

```
load 'web/gethttp'
gethttp 'g.co'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python + requests, <s>55</s> <s>53</s> 50 bytes

```
from requests import*
print(get('http://ai').text)
```

-2 bytes by switching URLs
-3 bytes thanks to ovs

Comment: Aren't shortened URLs usually disallowed?

Comment: Really, that's Python + requests, since requests is (sadly) not in the standard library.

Comment: `from request import*` is 2 bytes shorter

Comment: @Shaggy Um... Welp... pretty much every other answer used one rip. But I changed my URL to make it even shorter because apparently `http://ai` is a valid full URL..

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, 2 + 12 = 14 bytes

```
gf
```

Expects the URL `http://3.ly/` as input. `gf` opens the current file under the cursor. Thanks to netrw, this works fine for URLs. I found this just now while trying to remember the command to open URLs in your browser (found it, it's [`gx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9459366/2093695)).

Answer (score 0):

## HTML, 24 bytes

```
<iframe src="http://ai">
```

This technically fails as it renders the result...

Comment: Is that not STDOUT for HTML? 15 bytes: `<embed src=//ai`

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell, 62 bytes

PowerShell 5

```
-join[char[]][net.webclient]::new().downloaddata('http://ai.')
```

66 bytes for more older versions of PowerShell

```
-join[char[]](new-object net.webclient).downloaddata('http://ai.')
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/), 31 bytes

```
URLDownloadToFile,http://g.co,g
```

There's a built-in so it's not very exciting. Try to fashion, though, the function is fairly long.

Answer (score 0):

### Bash + wget, 7 bytes

```
wget ai
```

Downloads the page at http://ai

Comment: I get "Resolving ai... failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known." with this, though `wget ai.` (with a trailing dot) works.

Comment: @Kevin Works on my system. Sounds like you're on FreeBSD or macOS.

Comment: Yes, macOS Sierra

Comment: @Kevin I'm on Linux. Try a VM.

Comment: Odd that it wouldn't work on macOS, since it should be the same code (modulo some os-specific compiler flags, which I wouldn't expect to change this) and `nslookup`, `dig`, and `nc` all find it fine. Oh well, not the first difference I've seen, and not worth installing a vm for.

Comment: @Kevin I think DNS resolution works slightly differently on BSD systems

Comment: `w3m ai` is probably valid too

Comment: @DigitalTrauma What is `w2m`?

Comment: @Mendeleev https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3m

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 27 + 10 = 37 bytes

```
puts open('http://ai').read
```

+10 bytes for `-ropen-uri` flag (to require open-uri library)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 + 11 = 15 bytes

```
jk'z
```

With URL `http://v.ht` as input. Takes an URL string as input, downloads the file, and prints its content.

Explanation:

```
jk'z
   z    Get the input string (URL)
  '     Download the file from the URL, return a list of lines
jk      Join the list on k which is the empty string
```

Note that we cannot use the function `s` for concatenating the list because of bytes types issues.

**Slightly cheating, 2 + 11 = 13 bytes** (it displays the list of the lines in the file instead of a single string for the whole file):

```
'z
```

You will need to install Pyth on your machine to test it (the online interpreter does not execute unsafe operations).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Pretty good, but "the url must count to byte count".

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 76 bytes

```
Console.WriteLine(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://3.ly"));
```

Answer (score 0):

### MATLAB, 20 bytes

```
urlread('http://ai')
```

Nothing fancy here...

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
.w
```

Beats all other answers. Takes `ai` as input.

Comment: > Input should be empty, or the URL you wish to download

Comment: @emanresuA It is the URL I wish to download. Also, see my post on [Tips for golfing in 05AB1E](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224104).